# Convert Standalone Java Application to Deployable Web Application

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, servlets, jetty

I am new to Java EE.
I have a Standalone maven project which I need to make war deployable project. It contains many servlets & embedded-Jetty is used to run them.

Step which I have done:

- Made a new Maven project with archtype-webapp.
- Copy all the servlets and other classes in src/main/java
- Added those servlets to web.xml

The original project contains a main which sets up the jetty server and does a initial login check and initializes all the servlets.

Can someone explain what exactly happens when we run a program as run on server.
What gets executed first (like main in standalone program).

Comment: It begins its  excutes with index.jsp or index.html page or etc.. which ever jsp or html page mentioned in  <welcome-file-list> tag of web.xml file

Comment: Thanks for the info. I want to run a particular class for login credential  validation ,whenever user starts the server & types localhost:8080.  Could you help me how to do that.(That is just a class not a servlet)

Comment: please stick to the question... what ever you asked in comment for that you must have login jsp page use java beans for invoking java classes from jsp.. the best way i would suggest is jsp--> servlet--> java class..

Comment: Sorry for deviating but still I am unable to fulfill the requisite task. I got that for servlet mapping I need to write in web.xml but was wondering how would I implement main function or any other class which is not servlet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: for other classes you don't need to map any thing, just invoke that class from servlet... in same way you do it for accessing methods of one class from other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick list of what happens-

- As you open the url, e.g. http://localhost:8080/AppName, the file mentioned in the welcome file is served in the browser.
- You can have an HTML form here with fields for login id and password, and the url in the of the servlet which will be invoked when the form is submitted.
- Your servlet would be invoked and from thereon you can do whatever you want, call whatever class you want to call.

This is the most basic form, you might want to start with a simple web application to understand the basics before you start converting your application. That will allow you to understand the flow and then adapt your code accordingly.

Hope this helps.